# How to set format DateTimeOffset in Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

```
public DateTimeOffset CreateAt { get; set; }
public timeFormat()
    {
        this.CreateAt = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Result: 4/29/2020 10:18:43 AM +07:00

How to set format datetime in CreateAt to (4/29/20 10:18 AM) in view page?

Comment: Are you looking to display the date somewhere in that format? E.g. on a view somewhere

Comment: yes i want to display on view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you can format the date time string however you would like

For example this code

```
@Model.CreatedAt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm tt")
```

would output:  29-04-2020 10:18 AM

See the docs for all formatting options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1):

A DateTimeOffset is timezone aware, so you would have to use DateTime instead if you do not want any offset information saved.
If you want to change the offset you can do that with the DateTimeOffset.ToOffset(TimeSpan) Method.